# Cannot catch oracle exception from oracle stored procedure using php oci

Tags: php, oracle, exception, stored-procedures

Does anyone know how to catch oracle exception in php?
I have a stored procedure which raise exceptions when something occur and I want to pass the message directly to browser. I have tried using try catch and oci_error but still unable to catch the exception. I want to catch something like this from oracle stored procedure

```
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20101, 'SOME EXCEPTION');
```

and send 'SOME EXCEPTION' to browser.

In the php code I'm using codeigniter but I could not call the procedure using the driver provided by it so I make my own function. It's quite similar to the one provided by codeigniter but I don't know why mine works. Here is the function to call the stored procedure

```
 
public function oci_procedure_call($package_name, $proc_name, $param)
{
    $sql = "begin $package_name.$proc_name(";

    foreach ($param as $p) {
        $sql .= $p['name'] . ',';
    }

    $sql = trim($sql, ',') . '); end;';

    $stmt = oci_parse($this->db->conn_id, $sql);

    foreach ($param as $p) {
        oci_bind_by_name($stmt, $p['name'], $p['value'], $p['length'], $p['type']);
    }

    try {
        $r = oci_execute($stmt);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        log_message('info', print_r($e, true));
    }

    if (!$r) {
        $e = oci_error($this->db->conn_id);
        return $e['message'];
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: for further reference would you mind showing a bit of your php code? And also, welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you for that :). I have added my php code. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Mark Can you change your code to something like this: http://pastebin.com/Bv2BbTWd (notice the block-commented parts and the parts come after them) and try again?

Comment: @Passerby I have tried using the code you provided in the link but it couldn't get pass this line `$sql.=implode(",",array_column($param,"name"));`. It just stopped there. I have tried changing that line with my original code which was fine and could go through the rest of the code but there was no difference.

Comment: @Passerby sorry, it was my mistake, my php version is 5.3.8. I'll try it again.

Comment: @Mark The `array_column` part is not necessary; it just look cleaner and make use of built-in array functions. The essential part is `$param[$key]["value"]`, because `$p` is changing in the loop, so if you bind `$p["value"]` you _may_ end up with every placeholder binding to the last `$p` value.

Comment: @Mark Also, I notice that your function return either `true` or a possibly-non-empty-string, which may evaluate to `true` if loosy-compared (`"a"==true` IS true). Are you using strict compare to check the function return value?

Comment: @Passerby you're right, I've changed the return value. I've also noticed that it raised an exception, but `$e` in `catch(Exception $e)` holds no value. Any idea?

Comment: @Mark The [PHP doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-execute.php) doesn't mention that `oci_execute` will raise exception. I guess you raising error on Oracle side will only causes `oci_execute` to return false, so you still need to depend on `oci_error`.